# Why is remove() only removing the first element from the list in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

So, I working on a problem where there is a **list lt=[1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5] and k =1**.So, I am trying to remove all the occurrences of k from the list and return the list but when I use the in built method remove() it only deletes the first occurrence while ignoring the the other occurrences. **The output I receive is [1,3,4,5,5] and output I expect is [3,4,5,5]** Below is my code , thank you.

```
class Solution(object):

    def remove_occurances(self, lt, k):

        i = 0
        while i < len(sorted(lt)):
            if lt[i] == k:
                lt.remove(lt[i])
                i += 1
            return lt


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5]
    k = 1
    print(Solution().remove_occurances(p, k))
```

Comment: yes, it only removes one element(the first occurrence)

Comment: What do you think `return lt` does?  *When* do you think it does it?

Comment: Where am I going wrong ? I want to remove all the occurrences of '1' and return the list.

Comment: Rather than doing `while i < len(sorted(lt)):` you can do `while k in lt:`. That way it will loop until all occurrences of `k` are removed.

Answer (score 4):

Within `remove_occurances` you could instead have:

```py
def remove_occurances(self, lt, k):
    while k in lt:
        lt.remove(k)

    return lt
```

Note that this function is working directly on the input list, so the `remove` calls will alter that input list. Also the returned list `lt` will be the *same* list (i.e., a pointer to the same memory rather than a copy) as this input list `lt`.

If you want the original input list to be unaltered, you'd need to do something like:

```py
def remove_occurances(self, lt, k):
    newlist = list(lt)  # make a copy of lt
    while k in newlist:
        newlist.remove(k)  # remove from the copy

    return newlist  # return the copy
```

This will keep looping while the list `lt` still contains the value `k`.

Comment: So , there is no need to use if statement?

Comment: Yes, the `if` statement isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: Thank you, I also had another question, if we have to measure the speed of execution , like which code runs better , can we do it IDE? I use Pycharm.

Comment: One of the simplest ways I use to measure the speed of execution using the [`%timeit` IPython magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) command within an IPython terminal session. See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/ipython.html) for how to use IPython within Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning too quickly:

```py
def remove_occurances(self, lt, k):

    i = 0
    while i < len(sorted(lt)):
        if lt[i] == k:
            lt.remove(lt[i])
        else:
            i += 1
    
    return lt
```

Outputs:

```
[3, 4, 5, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you, I am understanding the indentations in Python, I am new to Python so some times I get jumbled up . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should remove in loop.

Not to remove from a specific location, but to remove a specific value, as long as it exists in the list.

When there is no more of this array - it will raise a valueEttor, and you will know that all the requested values have been removed.

```
   try:
        while True:
            lt.remove(k)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

EDIT:
to measure time:

```
    from time import time

    start_time = time()

    try:
        while True:
            lt.remove(k)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    end_time = time()
     
        
    print("TOTAL TIME: " + str(end_time-start_time))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
p = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5]
k = 1
def remove_occurances(p, k):
    return [i for i in p if i != k] # here we are using list comprehension and taking only values expect the value to be removed.
remove_occurances(p, k)
#[3, 4, 5, 5]
```

Comment: I'd imagine the downvote is because this is a code only answer, with no explanation of what you're doing/why it solves the problem (not my downvote btw)